# how can i return 404 http status from dropwizard

Tags: dropwizard

new to dropwizard! is there anyway that I can manually return different http status codes from the apis? basically something similar to this!

```
@GET
@Timed
public MyObject getMyObject(@QueryParam("id") Optional<String> id) {
    MyObj myObj = myDao.getMyObject(id)
    if (myObj == null) {
          //return status.NOT_FOUND; // or something similar 
          // or more probably 
          // getResponseObjectFromSomewhere.setStatus(mystatus)

    }

    return myObj;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would recommend using the JAX-RS Response object instead of returning your actual domain object in the response. It serves as an excellent standard for including metadata with your response object and provides a nice builder for handling status codes, headers, customer content types, etc.

```
//import javax.ws.rs.core.Response above
@GET
@Timed
public Response getMyObject(@QueryParam("id") Optional<String> id) {
  MyObject myObj = myDao.getMyObject(id)
  if (myObj == null) {
    //you can also provide messaging or other metadata if it is useful
    return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build()
  }
  return Response.ok(myObj).build();
}
```

Comment: The dropwizard doc states that throwing WebApplicationException should be prefered to returning a Response (see http://dropwizard.io/manual/core.html#responses), that makes your jersey resources classes more testable. But yes, both work.

Comment: Because I can test an Exception was thrown vs a response code? I know you're citing their docs, but I disagree with that being objectively easier.

Comment: Here's a current link to what @ChristopheFurmaniak mentioned https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/0.9.2/docs/manual/core.html#error-handling

Answer (score 16):

It's as simple as throwing a [`WebApplicationException`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.11/jersey/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html).

```java
@GET
@Timed
public MyObject getMyObject(@QueryParam("id") Optional<String> id) {
  MyObject myObj = myDao.getMyObject(id)
  if (myObj == null) {
    throw new WebApplicationException(404);
  }
  return myObj;
}
```

As you get further along you may want to put together custom exceptions which you can [read more about here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6559).

Comment: or "throw new WebApplicationException(javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);" to avoid magic values and using already declared constants.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to return an `Optional<MyObject>`. Dropwizard will automatically throw a 404 when your result is `Optional.absent()` or `Optional.empty()` if you use the dropwizard-java8 bundle.

Just do:

```
@GET
@Timed
public Optional<MyObject> getMyObject(@QueryParam("id") Optional<String> id) {
    Optional<MyObject> myObjOptional = myDao.getMyObject(id)
    return myObjOptional;
}
```

Obviously you need to update your DAO according by returning `Optional.fromNullable(get(id))` for Guava or `Optional.ofNullable(get(id))` for Java8 bundle.

There is no need to play around with custom `Response` objects unless you want to return a custom status code outside of `200` and `404`

Comment: Elegant and works great (dw 1.0.3, java 8). I'd make this the accepted answer if I could